# Are there any 'hard and fast rules' in terms of structuring HTML for the purposes of a collapsible menu?

Tags: html, css

Looking into responsive navigation components, such as provided by the [React-md](https://react-md.mlaursen.com/components/navigation-drawers) library, I see that the Side navigation is a `<div>` that is added to the DOM just under the header, and displayed in position via an animation.

So in this case the structure of the navigation is:

```
<div>
  <header />
  <div id="nav" />
</div>
```

Are there any hard / fast rules regarding how to structure a navigation pane? For example, it could be possible to structure like so:

```
<div>
  <header>
    <navPane style={left: -200px, display static}>
  </hader>
</div>
```

Is there an 'optimal' approach to structuring a UI shell / navigation drawer that an experienced developer would probably know to choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what your page should look like on which devices.

Where should it be scrollable if content is to much?

Should it be rendering fast on scrolling the content? onscroll animation positioning then isn't a good idea.

I only would put the `navPane` in the `header`, if the `navPane` should be horizontal and not a vertical drawer.

These are, in my opinion, the most useful cascading basics. Number 3 and 4 are my favorites, giving the best "native app" feeling from desktop over tablet to mobile, you could have a sticky header and the nav/sidebar could slide over the content on mobile.

*the following is pseudo HTML, so i don't need classes or divs, the sidebar could contain e.g. a nav-drawer. the wireframes are tablet/desktop*

### 1. Header and footer in full width above/under sidebar and main-content

[image]

```html
<header/>
<content>
    <sidebar/>
    <main/>
</content>
<footer/>
```

### 2. Sidebar in full height, header only over main content, footer in full-width below sidebar and content

[image]

```html
<sidebar/>
<content>
    <header/>
    <main/>
</content>
<footer/>
```

### 3. Header in full width, sidebar in full height to main-content wrapper, footer below actual main-content

[image]

```html
<header/>
<content>
    <sidebar/>
    <main-wrapper>
        <main/>
        <footer/>
    </main-wrapper>
</content>
```

### 4. Sidebar in full height, header and footer above/under main-content

[image]

```html
<sidebar/>
<content>
    <header/>
    <main/>
    <footer/>
</content>
```

### Where will it scroll?

An image example of what's possible with **3**.

- Header stays at top
- Sidebar and content are independently scrollable.
- Footer is on bottom of content, but not over content - when content is big enough to be scrollable

[image]

Screen a little bigger in height, no scrolling.
[image]

More height, footer still at bottom of page.

[image]

Nothing is positioned through `position: fixed`, only sidebar-over-content on mobile would be needing `fixed`. The scrolling is controlled through setting `display: flex; min-height: 100vh` on first wrapping `div`, in the next ones `display: flex; overflow: auto;` with mostly `height: 100%`.

`display: flex` and `overflow: auto` leverages the scrolling down the tree, so not the whole page scrolls.

Wireframe for image example:
[image]

It is a little more complex then **3** alone, but it is based on **3**.

It got boundaries for displaying loading, error states (and so on). Those are `content-pane`, `content`, `editor-pane`, the `editor-panes` could have n sidebars and contains the actual `content` with `footer`.

Comment: I was kind of hoping for a magical "this is the only way to do it properly". But I didn't really expect there to be such a thing. Thank you very much for your answer. The diagrams on the different layouts are very helpful. I have experience with (4) - https://react-md.mlaursen.com/. But I also like number 3. I'm actually looking into using other component libraries where navigation components haven't been made yet (IBM's carbon design), which is why I'm looking into options on how to do it

Comment: The images actually look like number (4) nested within number (3)?

Comment: I have added the wireframe of the images with an explanation, the most difference to 2 are the n-sidebars and boundaries.
Sadly (or for good?) a one-and-only way for styling UI doesn't exist, even technical needs could result in an "oh i must change that and that". Not every software and user flow/workflow profits from the same layout, some need that and others need something else.